# I'm having a hard time to bulk rename files using os.rename

Tags: python

My code:

```
import os

videos = {}
subtitles = {}

files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
for file in files:
 if (file[-3:] == "ass" or file[-3:] == "srt"):
  episode = file.split('#')[1].split(' ')[0]
  subtitles[episode] = file

 if (file[-3:] == "mp4"):
  episode = str(int(file.split('ep')[1].split('.')[0]))
  videos[episode] = file


i = 1
for sub in subtitles:
 try:
  extension = str(subtitles.get(str(i)))[-3:]
  video = str(videos.get(str(i))).split('.')[0]+"."+extension
  subtitle =  str(subtitles.get(str(i)))
  print (subtitle + video)
  os.rename(subtitle, video) # <---- 
  i+= 1
 except Exception as e:
  print ("Error: " + sub + " exception: " + str(e))
```

If I comment the line "os.rename(subtitle, video)", leaving only the print command, it prints all the file names normally, but if I don't comment it, all the file names become "None", giving me this error for every single file:

```
NoneNone.one
Error: 99 exception: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'None' -> 'None.one'
```

Comment: I did exactly that. It gives me "None", but if I comment the `os.rename` line it prints the right name. That's the weird thing.

Comment: What do you mean by "prints normally"? What's the exact output?

Comment: Why are you renaming a subtitle file with a video file?

Comment: solved it, thanks for trying to help

Comment: If you've solved your issue, it's usually a good idea to post the solution as an answer and accept it so other people can see it if they end up having the same problem.